# logical deduction question

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

For example:

S ::= “Sales will go up.”
E ::= “Expenses will go up.”

Express the following: Both sales and expenses will fall.

Why is it  ¬ (S ∧ E) 
instead of ¬S ∧ ¬E ?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, $\neg S:=$"sales will **NOT** go up" which is clearly different from saying that sales will fall. Basically, logical opposite versus polar opposite.

"It is not true that both sales and expenses will go up" can be trivially translated into symbols by $\neg (S \land E)$ which is logically equivalent to $\neg S \lor \neg E$.

Perhaps consider editing your question because there seems to be some issues that probably only you can rectify.

Comment: I have one problem. Why is "NOT go up" different from "will fail"? We are dealing with binary logic here. So, both should mean the same, no?

Comment: Sales could stay the same and likewise with expenses which is technically not going up. At least in my book, I suppose there could be a book that defines these things differently. I was interested in taking the LSAT before I became interested in...other things (to quote one of my math profs from undergrad).
:)

Comment: As far as binary logic goes (which is the norm), a statement is either true or false. There is no in-between. What you're saying is the same as saying we can't say a sequence is increasing once we establish it's non-decreasing. That's true. But, as far as the argument here goes, I think they mean the same, just as adding a constraint of monotonicity to my analogy makes it true.

Comment: I do see your point. I am just more comfortable saying "not go up" (I am uncomfortable with any language), unless I am told fall means the same (I consider it to otherwise mean decrease).

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is a bit flawed. The expression $\neg (S \land T)$ means "Both S and T are not true." (i.e. at least one of them is false.)

$\neg S \land \neg T$ means "Both S and T are false."

Comment: it was me ... fair trade

Comment: @MattAPelto Technically, you won the type race. +1